# writing a few conditions in one function on python

Tags: python, function, pycharm

```py
def chocolate_maker(small, big, x):
    
     """
    :param small : small:is the num of the small chocolate bar chunks
    :param big : is the num of the big chocolate bar chunks
    :param x : total length of chocolate bar combining
    :return : returns true if the small+big == x or small*1== x or big*5 == x
    """
    if small * 1 + big * 5 == x or small * 1 == x or big * 5 == x:
        return True
    else:
        return False


print(chocolate_maker(3, 1, 3))
```

i need a brief review on my code, like if i can make it more efficiently, like maybe splitting the conditions.

Comment: why have small * 1? small will still be the same number

Comment: `if x return True else return False` can be simplified to `return x`.

Comment: If a boolean return type is required, though, OP should return `bool(x)`.

Comment: `return x in (a := small * 1, b := big * 5, a + b)` That's shorter but definitely not efficiently and way more implicit. Your option is good enough, the only update I'd make is to return condition immediately `return small * 1 + big * 5 == x or small * 1 == x or big * 5 == x`.

Comment: There is really no reason to include walrus here.  `return x in (small, big*5, small + big*5)`.

Comment: Your comments do not match your code.

Comment: Requests for code reviews should be made on [Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead

Comment: @Guimoute, there is a reason - it prevents recalcualtion.

Comment: @OlvinRoght Sure but it's not like we should sacrifice readability for something as cheap as summing two numbers. It's not two 1M entries numpy arrays.

Comment: @Guimoute, it's discussible about readability, but you've probably missed part where I said that this method is implicit itself and not recommended replacement of current code from question.

Answer (score 1):

Writing conditions on different lines can increase readability. But this is a simple calculation and your version is efficient enough.

```py
def chocolate_maker(small: int, big: int, x: int) -> bool:

    return (
        small + big * 5 == x 
        or small == x 
        or big * 5 == x
    )
```

Comment: This is much easier to read. I might also suggest https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#any